# Using console.log() in js

Tags: google-chrome-extension

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where to read console messages from background.js in a Chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257301/where-to-read-console-messages-from-background-js-in-a-chrome-extension)

I am trying to write my first Google Chrome extension. All I am trying to do is is create an extension that writes a string, via console.log(), to the console when the extension's browser action icon is clicked.

Here is my manifest.json:

```
{
  "name": "My Extension",
  "description": "My Extension",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": ["tabs"],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["test.js"]
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "My Extension",
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

And here is test.js:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) { console.log('testing'); });
```

I have the console open in Chrome but when I click my extension's icon nothing is displayed in the console. I've tried reloading the extension but it hasn't helped.

I am abviously doing something wrong.

Any advice would be much appreciated.
LT

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your script runs in the background page, so the message will be displayed in the background page's console.

- Open the **Extensions** page.
- Make sure that **Developer mode** is checked.
- Under **My Extension**, click **_generated_background_page.html** to inspect it.
- Click on the **Console** tab.

Comment: It now lives somewhere different: On the Extensions page > Inspect views >
service worker